# Find all combinations of numbers that will give a target mean

Tags: r, combinations, mean

I have a set of numbers and a given mean. I need to find the most efficient way to find a combination of those numbers, which would give the target mean.

```
numbers<-c(8.05,7.59,5.52,6.73,8.01,7.44,7.35,7.42,6.05)
target_mean<-7.34
```

I was thinking to use `combn` function (`combinat` package) to generate all possible combination of numbers and then find the means for all of them and see which ones would match my target mean, but I'm wondering if there is a better way. The problem is also that I don't know how many of those numbers make up my target mean.

Comment: floating number comparison should be careful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Akrun mentioned, it's not easy to match floating point numbers exactly. However, here's how to find the combinations with a mean +/-0.01 above and below your target:

```
target_mean<-7.34
numbers<-c(8.05,7.59,5.52,6.73,8.01,7.44,7.35,7.42,6.05)
res <- Map(combn, list(numbers), seq_along(numbers), simplify = FALSE)
res2 <- unlist(res, recursive = FALSE)[lapply(unlist(res, recursive = FALSE),mean)<(target_mean+.01)&
 lapply(unlist(res, recursive = FALSE),mean)>(target_mean-.01)]

res2
[[1]]
[1] 8.05 7.59 5.52 8.01 7.44 7.42

[[2]]
[1] 8.05 7.59 5.52 8.01 7.44 7.35 7.42

sapply(res2,mean)
[1] 7.33833 7.34000
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!